# Left outer join for first row in group only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
BANK        ACCOUNT_NAME    EXCESS  DEBT
Acme Bank   Checking1       500     300
Acme Bank   Personal        200     100
Bank One    Business        100     50
```

I need a sql query that returns.

```
BANK        ACCOUNT_NAME    EXCESS  DEBT    AVAILABLE
Acme Bank   Checking1       500     300     300
Acme Bank   Personal        200     100     NULL
Bank One    Business        100     50      50
```

AVAILABLE would be the `Sum(EXCESS) - Sum(DEBT)` grouped by `BANK`.  AVAILABLE would then appear only on the first row of BANK-ACCOUNT_NAME combination.  How do I do this?

My first attempt results in AVAILABLE having values on **all rows**, which not intended.  I only want the **first row in the group** to have an AVAILABLE value.

```
SELECT
    outer.BANK
    ,outer.ACCOUNT_NAME
    ,outer.EXCESS
    ,outer.DEBT
    ,inner2.AVAILABLE
FROM BankBalances AS outer
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            Bank
            ,SUM(EXCESS) - SUM(DEBT) AS AVAILABLE
        FROM BankBalances AS inner
        GROUP BY Bank
        WHERE outer.BANK = inner.BANK
    ) AS inner2
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` the results are unpredictable and at the whim of the query planner. There is no innate reason why the Checking1 record is "the first row in the group" instead of Personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT BANK, ACCOUNT_NAME, EXCESS, DEBT,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BANK ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NAME) = 1 
          THEN SUM(EXCESS) OVER (PARTITION BY BANK) - 
               SUM(DEBT) OVER (PARTITION BY BANK) 
          ELSE NULL 
       END AS AVAILABLE
FROM BankBalances
```

You can use windowed version of `SUM` in order to avoid `CROSS APPLY`. `ROW_NUMBER` is simply used to check for first row.

I have made the assumption that *first* row is considered the one having the 'minimum' `ACCOUNT_NAME` value within each `BANK` partition.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad7a8/1)

Comment: Thank you.  The assumption is fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `SUM OVER()` with Partition by like this.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT
    BANK
    ,ACCOUNT_NAME
    ,EXCESS
    ,DEBT
    ,SUM(EXCESS - DEBT)  OVER(PARTITION BY BANK) AS AVAILABLE,
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BANK ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NAME ASC) rn
FROM BankBalances
)
SELECT BANK
    ,ACCOUNT_NAME
    ,EXCESS
    ,DEBT
    ,CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN AVAILABLE ELSE null end as AVAILABLE 
FROM CTE
```